# Thymeleaf: Occasional error using #session - Exception evaluating SpringEL expression

Tags: thymeleaf, cas

We are using Spring webflow + ThymeLeaf and trying to access session.getAttribute() in html page.

Bit new to Thymeleaf and I understand Thymeleaf has 2 ways to address session viz. ${session.something} and ${#session.getAttribute('something')}.

Code we are using is something like below which fails occasionally.

```
<div th:if="${(#session.getAttribute('booleanAttribute'))}">  
...
</div>
```

In local environment I never see the failures, and it works as expected. In production this fails appox. 200 times in 30 minutes with following error -

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException:  Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "(#session.getAttribute('booleanAttribute'))" (template: "base" - line 80, col 10)
```

I am little reluctant to place null checks to see if (#session) is null or not without understanding why working locally fine. So I have this question -

What might be wrong above and how can I reproduce locally so that I can confirm fix I am placing will work across all environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#web-context-objects):

> `#session` : direct access to the javax.servlet.http.HttpSession object associated with the current request.

In my testing, `#session` is null when the session expires. In cases where a user has their session expired, using `#session` would throw a null point exception (`Method call: Attempted to call method getAttribute(java.lang.String) on null context object`). You should be able to test this by deleting your `JSESSIONID` cookie.

`${session}` on the other hand is a `SessionAttributesMap`, which appears to never be null -- even when there isn't a valid session.  In that case, the expression `${session.booleanAttribute}` would still work, just evaluate to false.